# Steam Park: Should danari count be secret from other players?

Tags: steam-park

In [Steam Park](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/121410/steam-park), the danari values are only printed on one side, and the other sides are all the same. This suggests to me that a player's total should be kept hidden.

If it's intended to be an *option*, it's not documented.

Comment: From what I see every gain of danari are in set amounts so a player would know how many you have if they are keeping track. I am guessing they come in multiple values just to keep the number of tokens down.

Comment: FWIW, Tom Vasel agrees that you can keep your total hidden. T=7:40 of his review here: https://boardgamegeek.com/video/37496/steam-park/dice-tower-reviews-steam-park

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have it correct.

The designer demonstrates hiding his income when explaining the prototype of the game in 2012. (T=8:23 of [this video](https://vimeo.com/27740372))

He says explicitly in [this video](https://boardgamegeek.com/video/35962/steam-park/steam-park-boardgamegeek-booth-spiel-2013) from Spiel 2013: "Money are kept secret." (T=9:48)

Later video reviews and/or game play explainer videos also concur:

- [Tom Vasel (T=7:40)](https://boardgamegeek.com/video/37496/steam-park/dice-tower-reviews-steam-park)
- [Dice Tower (T=10:02)](https://boardgamegeek.com/video/38931/steam-park/game-boy-geek-dice-tower-reviews-steam-park)

Comment: Wow, impressive research!

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer clear rules text that make the rule explicit, of course, though. :-)